# test if all files in directory have correct permissions

Tags: linux, bash, file, permissions

How can I test if all files in directory have correct permissions ? Using command `stat --format %a /home/user/dir/*` I can get permissions of all files in a directory in a multi line string. Let's say I want check if all files have permissions 0700.

I use `if [ "$(stat --format %a ~/file)" != 600 ]; then chmod 0600 ~/file; fi`  for single file, but how can I test multiple files ?

Comment: I suggest to take a look at GNU find's option `-perm`.

Comment: If you want to just change the permissions of all files inside a directory, then just change it directly using `chmod 600 directory/*`. I can't see why you would want to complicate this by finding a file and then changing its permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
for i in ~/your_dir/*/*
do
 if [ "$(stat --format %a $i)" != 600 ]; then
  chmod 0600 $i
 fi
done
```

Comment: yes, this was simple, could come up with that myself, thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Find will do all this work for you

```
find <directory> ! -perm -664 -exec chmod 0600 '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

the easy way is find.

for all files within a directory

"%a %n" will show the permission and the filename

```
find . -exec stat -c "%a %n" '{}' \;
```

Comment: But that checks nothing. The question was not "display permission on console". But "check if some permissions are set".